# Не( )дешевое – слитное или раздельное написание в данном примере?

Tags: частица-не, слитно-раздельно

*Думаю, даже для твоих москвичей взятие велосипедов напрокат – удовольствие

**не( )дешевое**.*
Можно ли в зависимости от вкладываемого в предложение смысла писать и слитно, и раздельно? Если здесь подразумевается "не самое дешевое" и синоним "дорогое" не накладывается на проверяемое слово, значит, можно писать раздельно?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы правы, можно писать и так и так в зависимости от смысла.

Если смысл "довольно дорогое", как вы правильно заметили, надо писать слитно, а если имеется в виду, что такое удовольствие не является дешёвым, то тогда надо писать раздельно. Ваше "не самое дешёвое" не совсем о том, мне кажется.